# jsrender template will not render, any ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

Can anyone tell me why this template will not render?

I am rendering it like so:

```
 var v = jQuery.url().param("id");
        jQuery.ajax({
            post: "POST",
            url: "svc.asmx/FetchNewsDetail",
            dataType: "text",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { 'id': v },
            success: function (data) {

                jQuery("#blog").append(jQuery("#newsSingleTemplate").render(data));
            }
        });
```

here is my json string for which i receive via web method (asp.net, asmx):

```
{"newsDetailId":1,"newsId":1,"newsItemTitle":"Make Your Reservations Before It\u0027s Too Late","newsItemDate":"\/Date(1400652000000)\/","newsItemBannerUrl":"img/news/bass_single_news.jpg","newsItemBannerAlt":"BASS Divisional","newsItemText":"Join us at the Noxon Reservoir in Trout Creek, Mont., for the 2014 B.A.S.S. Nation Western Divisional. This fishery is in the northwest corner of Montana, very close to Idaho and only a 2-hour drive to Canada. Montana has hosted B.A.S.S. Nation divisionals, but it has not hosted other levels of B.A.S.S. tournaments. Competitors will vie for the Western title May 21-23.","newsItemQuote":"I think what I like most about B.A.S.S. Nation divisionals is the opportunity to go to places that you don\u0027t often think of as well-known tournament destinations, such as Noxon in Montana and Lake Monroe in Indiana\"- Jon Stewart, director of the B.A.S.S. Nation"}{"d":null}
```

and here is my template

```
            <script id="newsSingleTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
            <article>
                <section class="first-column">
                    <header>
                        <h2>{{:newsItemTitle}}</h2>
                    </header>
                    <div class="date">
                        {{:newsItemDate}}
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        <img src="{{url:newsItemBannerUrl}}" width="670" height="300" alt="{{:newsItemBannerAlt}}" />
                        <br />{{:newsItemText}}</p>
                    <div id="slogan">
                        <h1>{{:newsItemQuote}}</h1>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </article>
            </script>
```

Thank you for your guy's help!

Answer (score 1):

Successfully tested with [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CXKyK/1/). Your question is not formulated very clearly. What exactly does not work? In which context is your template? What data structure are you using?

```
var template = $.templates("#newsSingleTemplate");

template.link("#result", data);
```

Answer (score 0):

It had to do with the {"d":null} at the end of my json string.

my ajax call was incorrect. Here is how to resolve the rendering issue.I don't understand why the data parameter is correct though.

```
var v = jQuery.url().param("id");
        jQuery.ajax({
            post: "POST",
            url: "svc.asmx/FetchNewsDetail",
            data: "id=" + v,
            success: function (data) {
                jQuery("#blog").html(jQuery("#newsSingleTemplate").render(data));
            }
        });
```